# How can I make a View scrollable in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to make a long view, for example, 3200*240, whatever. Now, I want to the user display from start from 0,0. When the user scroll right, the x index will increase 320. So, I need a scrollView on top of the UIView to detect the scroll? Also, I need to have a UIScrollViewDelegate, right? thank you.

Comment: A scrollview is a view itself. You do not need a view underneath, unless you have other requirements you're not telling us about.

Comment: But I want a separate view to handle scrolling, should I make a scrollview only?

Answer (score 0):

u make refer to this website http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/scrollview-example-in-iphone/ 
U just follow the step at there to do ur scroll view..

Comment: It appears you like that tutorial.